# Formatting JButtons in JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm having trouble getting my `JButtons` to appear where I want. For some reason all my buttons are appearing in the middle of the Panel when I want it to appear flushed with the top of the Panel, centered. I've tried manipulating different layout positioning such as BorderLayout.NORTH and GridBagConstraints.NORTH however I do not know if I utilizing it on the right components.
Currently my code has `A` Frame holding a JLayeredPane holding a `JSplitPane` with two JPanels in it so it has gotten quite confusing.

[image: This is what my code basically looks like.]

[image: And these are how the JButtons on the bottom Panel are appearing.]

Do you have any suggestions on how I can get the buttons to appear on the top of the Panel?

Comment: Just add the buttons to a JPanel using a FlowLayout. If you have more question the post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Post the code in the forum not as an image.

Comment: Oh sorry Ill post it there now.  I currently have the panel using a GridBagLayout so I can size the buttons the way I wanted them.  Is there a way for me to also implement the flow layout ?

Comment: Post code, not images.

Answer (score 0):

> I currently have the panel using a GridBagLayout

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use GridBagLayout for a working example and information about the constraints used by the layout manager.

> For some reason all my buttons are appearing in the middle of the Panel

Specifically read the section on the `weightx/y` constraints, which states that the components will clump together in the center unless you use non-zero values.